# What are the advantages of larger SMD pads at the ends of a SOIC land pattern?

Tags: pcb-design, surface-mount, footprint

I was looking at this [NXP TSSOP8 footprint](http://www.nxp.com/documents/reflow_soldering/sot505-1_fr.pdf) and was wondering why the end pads were 0.600 mm, and the non-end pads were 0.450 mm.

[image]

What advantages does this have?

Comment: Could this maybe be related to ["solder thieves"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37683/questions-on-mass-production-soldering) aka "robber pads" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's mostly for self centering purposes. It allows an IC to be misplaced by a small amount and self-correct during reflow.

But this seems to be mainly a NXP only recommendation. They make it for all of their TSSOP parts at least. Their generic SMD footprint and reflow document, [AN10365 Surface mount reflow soldering](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10365.pdf), doesn't address it (directly, unless I glossed over it). But they also reference IPC Standard IPC-7351 Generic requirements for Surface Mount Design and Land Pattern Standard. (You have to pay for standards).

Texas Instruments doesn't make this recommendation though: [Solder Pad Recommendations For Surface-Mount Devices](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbfa015a/sbfa015a.pdf).

And OnSemi only has an extended pad on pin 1 of some quad sided chips, mainly so that you can tell that that's supposed to be pin 1: [Soldering and Mounting Techniques
Reference Manual](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/SOLDERRM-D.PDF)

An Italian SMD manufacturer has an extensive [whitesheet](http://www.seritronics.it/download_italiano/seritronics%20_convegno%20saldatura2.pdf) on why this helps self-alignment during reflow, but it is in Italian.